How to remove a vdev device from a Solaris 10 ZFS pool
I added a disk to a Solaris 10 server and was trying to add the device to an existing single disk pool as a mirrored device however, instead of using the "zpool attach tank c1t5d0" command, I used "zpool add tank c1t5d0"
zpool status gives me the following output
pool tank -
state ONLINE -
config
    NAME          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank         ONLINE       0     0     0
        c1t4d0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        c1t5d0   ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
When I try to remove the device using zpool remove or detach or offline, I get the following errors.
#zpool offline tank c1t5d0: Cannot offline c1t5d0: no valid replicas
#zpool remove tank c1t5d0: Cannot remove c1t5d0: only inactive hot spares, cache, top-level, or log devices can be removed.
#zpool detach tank c1t5d0: Cannot detach c1t5d0: only applicable to mirror or replacing vdevs.
I tried # zpool add tank mirror c1t4d0 c1t5d0, but I get:
invalid vdev specification
Use '-f' to override the following error:
/dev/dsk/c1t4d0s0 is part of active ZFS pool tank. Please see zpool(1M).
When I use '-f' I get the following error:
invalid vdev specification
The following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/dsk/c1t4d0s0 is part of active ZFS pool tank. Please see zpool(1M).
I get the same errors with # zpool attach.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Likely dupe: https://serverfault.com/questions/1090055/can-i-remove-a-disk-from-a-zfs-stripe  TLDR: Not unless you have an updated version of ZFS - maybe the ability to remove a top-level zdev has been backported to Solaris 10 - you have kept your system updated?
